haben / sein for tanzen in Perfekt
I have a note that in Perfekt we use haben or sein.
Sein we use in case of description of movement or state change.
But in one exercise ("Welche Partizipien bilden das Perfekt mit haben? Wählen Sie.") which I did I saw that getanzt was expected to be used with haben. Dancing seems like a movement for me...
Is there any explanation why sein wasn't expected as an answer or it's just an exception to a general rule?

The "use sein for movement" rule is a bit of an oversimplification. Really it's more "use sein for change of state" but a "change of state" can mean a change of location where the verb tells you how that change of location happened. You normally think of dancing as an activity, not as a means of locomotion. In cases where people do dance from one place to another the auxiliary is sein as you might expect, see the Usage note in the Wiktionary entry.
Also, keep in mind that German grammar rules are full of exceptions, and sometime you just have to memorize things like auxiliary verbs. The rules help in the sense that you don't have to memorize the entire dictionary, but they are not foolproof. Hopefully there will not be "more exceptions to the rule than instances of it," as Mark Twain put it.

Either can be adequate based on the context.
The use of haben is eminently possible, as in the famous song "Ich hab' getanzt heut' Nacht", where the emphasis is obviously on the romantic atmosphere and circumstances of dancing and not on the movement (the dancer might move around the dance floor, but it is quite likely that they didn't get around further than a few dozen meters all night).
"Ich bin getanzt" would be used only if there is a strong sense of direction, usually conveyed by a prepositional phrase. (For instance, James Bond's dance partner might dance straight into a trap which kick-starts a rescue plot :-)
